# How to change if the i th bit is 1,replace with (i+1) bit in python?

Tags: python, replace, position, bit-manipulation, shift

for example read a number=23 and a bit position=2,after checking the i th position replace it with (i+1)th bit.

```
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
p = int(input("Enter a position: "))
print(bin(n))

def setBit(n, p):
   if(p == 1):
     n >> p+1
   return n

print(setBit(n,p))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way. Get the `i+1` bit. If it is a `1`, set the `i` bit else clear the `i` bit.

```
def setBit(number, bit_index):
    # Mask for p+1 bit
    mask = 1 << (bit_index + 1)
    # Read p+1 bit
    bit = number & mask
    # Mask for p bit
    mask = 1 << bit_index
    if bit:
        # Set bit
        number |= mask
    else:
        # Clear bit
        number &= ~mask
    return number

n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
p = int(input("Enter a position: "))
print(bin(n))
print(setBit(n,p))
```

Comment: Enter a number: 23
Enter a position: 2
0b10111
23  the result of this code .no response

Comment: @Mina I just made an update. Please check again.

Comment: Now it is OK. Tnx a lot

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as toggling the n-th bit if the n-th and the (n+1)-th bit are different, so you can also do this without an if by using xor:

```
def setBit(number, bit_index):
    t = number >> bit_index
    return number ^ (((t ^ (t >> 1)) & 1) << bit_index)
```